# Ignoring input characters on key down

Tags: javascript

I want to ignore certain characters in my phone input, so that the database just has digits. I know I can do this easy on server side (using PHP) but I am trying to understand js events a little better.. My question is this:

If I have a basic input:

```
var phoneInput = document.getElementById("phoneInput");
```

I can add an event listener using "onkeydown" which works fine

```
phoneInput.onkeydown = function(e){
  var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  var patt = /\d/;
  if(!patt.test(c)) return false;
};
```

But if I try doing the same thing using 'addEventListener', returning false seems to do nothing

```
phoneInput.addEventListener("keydown",function(e){
  var c = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
  var patt = /\d/;
  if(!patt.test(c)) return false;
});
```

I just don't understand why. Thanks in advance for any light you can shine on the subject..

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? Why don't you use `type="number"`? [You will still need support browsers that lack support.]

Comment: @epascarello it still allows for word characters even if I define the inputs type for number. (Im developing in firefox but I believe most browsers are the same with that)

Comment: I know but its an in-house application in a relatively small company (30 employees) so I tell them not to use IE with it. Plus I remove unwanted characters in PHP before I insert them into the database, but like I said I am just trying to understand the way JS handles these things. Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would strongly advise against changing the user's input or otherwise prevent them from typing something while they're doing it. It is confusing and leads to a bad user experience.

Ideally, you should keep your server-side validation and then use HTML5 features such as these:

```
<input type="number" /> Allows only numbers
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9. -]*" /> Allows numbers, spaces, periods and hyphens
<input type="text" required /> Specifies a required field
```

Modern browsers will prevent the form from being submitted and present helpful error message to the user (which you can customise with a `title` attribute).

However, for general reference, `return false;` doesn't necessarily cancel the event. To do that, you should use this:

```
// if you haven't already:
e = e || window.event;
// to cancel the event:
if( e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
return false;
```

Comment: Thanks! and yea I agree with the changing users inputs, I find it super annoying but I'm just trying a few different things and I thought it was weird that onkeydown and addEventListener("keydown", etc.. did not act the same --- stackoverflow is making me wait 3 mins to accept your answer but I will

Answer (score 5):

I had to do something similar for a project I'm working on. This is how I did it.

```
// prevent users from typing alpha/ symbol characters on select fields
$("#modal-region").on("keydown", "#markdown, #sku", function(e) {

    var key = e.which;
    // when a keydown event occurs on the 0-9 keys the value 
    // of the "which" property is between 48 - 57 
    // therefore anything with a value greater than 57 is NOT a numeric key

    if ( key > 57) {
        e.preventDefault();

    } else if (key < 48) {

    // we don't want to disable left arrow (37), right arrow (39), delete (8) or tab (9)
    // otherwise the use cannot correct their entry or tab into the next field!

        if (key != 8 && key != 9 && key != 37 && key != 39 ) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }

});
```