# How to ignore * input from keyboard in text box

Tags: javascript, html

I want to ignore * input from keyboard; 
I am trying following code; but after giving alert; '*' is printing in textbox

How can I ignore '*'?

My html code

```
 <input name="filterTextField" type="text" id="filterTextField" tabindex="2"  style="width: 240px;
    position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; z-index: 2;border:none;" onkeypress="asteriskValidation(event)" />
```

my java script

```
function asteriskValidation(event){ 
 var textValue = document.getElementById('filterTextField').value;
var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
                        if (charCode == 42)
                            { 
                                alert("asterix not allowed");
                                textValue = '';
                                return false;
                            }
                                else
                            {       
                                return true;
                            }
             }
```

Comment: `textValue` is just a variable, it doesn't refers to `filterTextField`.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302746/ignoring-input-characters-on-key-down

Comment: Why are you disallowing a user from typing an asterisk? I'd be very annoyed if I thought my keyboard was broken. Also, what happens if a user disables javascript and sends an asterisk to the server anyway? Something sounds off here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return value `onkeypress` event. Try:

```
<input name="filterTextField" type="text" id="filterTextField" tabindex="2"  style="width: 240px;
    position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 1px; z-index: 2;border:none;" onkeypress="return asteriskValidation(event)" />
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sYP8C/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rGk9V/)

```
 $("#filterTextField").keypress(function (evt) {
      var keycode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
      if (keycode  == 42) { //Enter key's keycode
        alert("asterix not allowed");
        return false;
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed how you access the textfield element.

If you just want to reset it, no need to return boolean.

Try

```
function asteriskValidation(event){   
    var text = document.getElementById('filterTextField'); 
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode == 42)
    { 
       alert("asterix not allowed");
       text.value = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make function like below

```
$("input").keypress(function (event) {
  var keycode = event.charCode || event.keyCode;
  if (keycode  == 42) {
    return false;
 }
});
```