# Why does my input field is being populated with a key that generated a focus event?

Tags: javascript, focus, dom-events, keyboard-events

I am listening for a `keydown` event and checking if it is the `/` key. if it is, I want to focus on a text input.

I'm doing it like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Press '/' to search">

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.key === '/' || event.code === 'NumpadDivide'){
        document.getElementById("search").focus();
    }
})
```

The above code does focus on the input, but its also inserting the `/` populating that input with the `/` key.

Here is a fiddle of the code:

https://jsfiddle.net/0v47rnxm/

Comment: So prevent it with `event.preventDefault();`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ignoring input characters on key down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302746/ignoring-input-characters-on-key-down)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to 'prevent' the regular behaviour of the keypress. Try adding;

`event.preventDefault()` as follows;

```
<input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Press '/' to search">

window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event){
    if(event.key === '/' || event.code === 'NumpadDivide'){
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("search").focus();
    }
})
```

Comment: As @SebastianSimon mentioned in the comment above, this is working, yes.